# Reactive page using usestate boolean value does not work in Reactnative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making reactive Navigator by using react-native expo

I want to make a code like this

```
if isLoggedin is false show <LoginContent props={props} />
```

```
if isLoggedin is true show <Text>user</Text>
```

When I did `console.log(isLoggedin)` the result was `undefined`

And My code doesn't work even if I change the `isLoggedIn` value.

This is App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';...

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigate() {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    // const changeCheck = () => {
    //     setIsLoggedIn((isLoggedIn) => !isLoggedIn);
    // };

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowColor: 'transparent' } }}
            drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} changeCheck={changeCheck} {...props} />}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Note" component={Note} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="CheckedList" component={CheckedList} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="UncheckedList" component={UncheckedList} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Support" component={Support} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

function Sidebar() {
    return (
        <>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <DrawerNavigate />
            </NavigationContainer>
        </>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar style={{ width: 100 }} />
        </>
    );
}
```

and this is the part of DrawerContect.js

```
import * as React from 'react';...

export function DrawerContent(props, { isLoggedIn, changeCheck }) {
    const press = () => {
        console.log(isLogginedIn);
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>

                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 20, flexDirection: 'column', marginVertical: 20 }}>
                        <View>{isLoggedIn ? <LoginContent props={props} /> : <Text style={Styles.title}>User</Text>}</View>
                    </View>
                </View>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever variables you have passed in DrawerContent will be accessible in first argument. So you need to destructure first argument which is props to get isLoggedIn.

```
export function DrawerContent(props) {
    const { isLoggedIn, changeCheck } = props; // change this
    const press = () => {
        console.log(isLogginedIn);
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>

                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 20, flexDirection: 'column', marginVertical: 20 }}>
                        <View>{isLoggedIn ? <LoginContent props={props} /> : <Text style={Styles.title}>User</Text>}</View>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

Comment: I changed `const {isLoggedIn, changeCheck} = props`
but It also shows `undefined`

Comment: I couldn't spell it out. I've solved it! Thank you so much!!!